# Could someone explain the logic here or what I am asking? (Boolean operations)

Tags: python

In Python 2.7

When asking the interpreter the following:

`(1 or 3) > 2` it returns `False`

Why is this? What am I effectively asking the interpreter, apparently not if either 1 or 3 is greater than two.

Similarly, asking `(1 or 5) in range(2,6)` also returns `False`

I am 100% sure it has to do with my (x or y) part of the statement, but again, why is this? I do not so much need a different way of stating something like this, as I understand I could just ask:

```
if x in range(2,6) or y in range(2,6):
```

But I was just wondering why it does not work!

Comment: `or` doesn't work how you think it does - it takes the left hand side, and right hand side, calls `bool()` on them both, and checks if either of the resulting values is `True`, and the first one that is is returned (or `False` if none do). The best way to do this would be `any(x > 2 for x in (1, 3))`.

Comment: @Lattyware, one small correction, it doesn't try to evaluate the right side if the left side evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @Gil True, I oversimplified it a little in my explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's examine `(1 or 3) > 2`:

- `(1 or 3)` is evaluated first, giving `1` (see [The Peculiar Nature of `and` and `or`](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html) if you're wondering why).
- `1 > 2` is evaluated next, giving `False`.

The correct way to express what you're trying to express is:

```
>>> 1 > 2 or 3 > 2
True
```

Another, more general, way is as follows:

```
>>> t = (1, 3)
>>> any(el > 2 for el in t)
True
```

Here, `t` can be any iterable.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you! It will not seperately evaluate every integer between parentheses, as for any two integers it will just return the first?

Comment: @Rym unless the first integer is `0`

Comment: +1 for the [link](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html), that is a great link. :)

Comment: Yet another way would be `max(1, 3) > 2`

Answer (score 0):

1 (understood as number) is evalued `true` (all numbers are evaluated to `true`, except 0), so there isn't the need to evalute 3 (understood as number).
This because you use an `OR` condition, that "stop" evaluation onto first `true` value that find.
So, is `1 > 2`? The answer is `false`

You have to decompose or if into two separate condition:

```
1 > 2 or 3 > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

1 corresponds to true. Thus the result for

```
1 or 3
```

is

```
1
```

and

```
1 > 2
```

is false.

And you could have known this if you had tried the answer for 
 `1 or 3`

in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the proper use case for boolean operations. The first should be:

```
(1 > 2) or (3 > 2)
```

The expression:

```
(1 or 3)  > 2
```

will first work out `1 or 3` then attempt to figure out if that is greater than two.

Similarly:

```
(1 or 5) in range(2,6)
```

is probably better expressed as either:

```
(1 in range(2,6)) or (5 in range(2,6))
```

or:

```
((1 >= 2) and (1 < 6)) or ((5 >= 2) and (5 < 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna throw my two cents into this question as well.

When Python evaluates your statement

```
(1 or 3) > 2
```

This is what it does, Hey! Let's take first number and call `bool()` on it. Any number here  that isn't `0` will be evaluated to `True` and return that.

You can try `(10000 or 3)`, it will always return the most left hand "variable" as long its not `0`

Example of the opposite would be if you had

```
(0 or 3)
```

It then goes on to evaluate the rest of the expression, which basically will say in pseudocode:

`returned number (wheter its the left or right) is greater than 2`

And this is where it gets weird, your expression will always then differ because of how the parenthesis was evaluated.
In your case it'll be

`1 > 2 == False` but `(0 or 3) > 2 == True`

As for the `range` part, the same logic applies.
In the parenthesis the left hand number will be "returned" and thusly, wont be available in your range check.

`(1 or 4) in range(2,5) == False`

Comment: If I had any more reputation I'd upvote this answer as well. Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: No worries, mate! Glad to help a bit! :)